# Get Column Header in TableCellCollection in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using a website and i have a gridview in that website.... I want to delete a row in that gridview by using that selected row column values and Column headers... i got the column values by using TablecellCollection but i cant get that column value's Corresponding Column header.... how shall i get that Column header by using TableCellCollection....

Please anyOne Tell me the solution of this....

Thanks in Advance!

And My code is:

```
           int Row = Convert.ToInt16(e.RowIndex);
           TableCellCollection collection = GrdViewDetails.Rows[Row].Cells;

           for (int i = 0; i < Collection.Cells.Count;i++)
           {
           strColumnValue = Collection.Cells[i].Text;
           //strColumnName=?
           }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 GrdViewDetails.Columns[i].HeaderText
```